# Resolve not defined in nested method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently working with a module in node called webshot js.  What this does is that it uses phantom js to take a screen shot of a web page.  The problem is that I need to wait for it to complete to continue doing some other code.  I decided to wrap this in a promise.

```
function takeWebshot() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      webshot('url', 'save.img.jpb', Someoptions)
    })
}
```

`webshot()` method is called by `var webshot = require('./lib/webshot');`

So then I went into the webshot js file and I added resolve() after Phantom exits

```
phantomProc.on('exit', function(code) {
      return resolve()
} also tried just resolve().
```

My incorrect line of thinking was that it would return resolve() and then the promise would resolve and I can execute takewebshot().then... etc.

However I get an error

```
webshot.js:242
      return resolve();
      ^

ReferenceError: resolve is not defined
```

What am I missing?  Obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: err... that's just not how it works. webshot was defined elsewhere, it doesn't close around `resolve` and therefore doesn't have access to it. You could make webshot accept a callback and pass resolve as that callback.

Comment: Ok in a situation like this then how would one add a promise to the method?  @KevinB

Comment: Either make webshot accept a callback or return a promise.

Comment: can you add a little more code so we can understand where you really want to resolve the promise and give solution to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, your code throws an error about `resolve` being undefined because variables in a given scope aren't passed to functions that are *called* within that scope.

One possible way to remedy this would be to assign the return value of the call within `takeWebShot` to a variable. This will hold up the main thread until the function returns, since it needs to wait for the return value in order to assign it to a variable (even if that value is undefined). Below that variable assignment, you can then resolve the promise. You could also resolve the promise *with* the return value if you have meaningful data you want to pass.

This is a bit of a compromise solution since it doesn't look like Webshot supports promises and it's probably overkill to implement that yourself.

```js
// Your script
function takeWebshot() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let t = webshot('url', 'save.img.jpb', Someoptions);
        resolve();
    })
}
```